# Fill an Array with Values to the next empty Row

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to fill an array from user inputs in an Excel worksheet. Currently I have the worksheet with only two targets listed but I want the capability for a user to define endless amounts of targets if desired.
my code:

The stop is there to debug, I get a subscript out of range on the Targets (i, 1) line. The while looks for values in a specific column and goes down rows until it detects a blank and then stops. I don't know how to get a value, once it is detected to be put into my array.

I have tried moving the ReDim of targets inside the loop and inside the while loop.

```
Dim max_I As Byte, tgt_N As Double
Dim Targets()
Dim RadarRangeDenomenator()
Dim RelativePower()
Dim PowerAmplitude()

Call Activ8_Sheet("Signal")

tgt_N = 0
max_I = 0

While Cells(max_I + 8, 3).Value <> ""
    tgt_N = tgt_N + 1
    max_I = max_I + 1
    For i = 1 To max_I
        Targets(i, 1) = Cells(max_I + 8, 3)
    Next i
    Stop
Wend

ReDim Targets(tgt_N)

MsgBox (Targets(1, 1))
```

What I want is to have a single dimension array (many rows but only 1 column) of values that are listed on the Excel sheet.

Comment: And just for the record, your comment of _".. to have a single dimension array ..."_ and the following statement _"(many rows but only 1 column)"_ contradicts itself. An array with 1 column is still a 2 dimensional array - with the 2nd dimension being 1 to 1.

Comment: Also, the reason for your ___Subscript out of Range___ error that you are receiving on that line is due to you not pre-dimensionalizing the array. This is typically done on a static basis: `Dim myArray(1 To 10, 1 To 1)` or can be done dynamically with the `ReDim` statement: `Dim myArray()` `ReDim myArray(1 To LastRow, 1 To 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping your cells, just assign the entire range to the array at once. This method automatically creates a 2-D array, because the worksheet itself is 2-D.

If you want the *very last cell* in the column, you could use this method:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Signal")

Dim StartRng As Range, EndRng As Range
Set StartRng = ws.Range("C8")
Set EndRng = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)

Dim Targets() As Variant
Targets = ws.Range(StartRng, EndRng).Value
```

`ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)` will scan the column from the last row of the worksheet, upwards. As soon as it finds a non-empty cell, it uses that cell for the range. This means there could still be empty cells above this in the column.

However, if you are wanting only the cell values to the very next empty cell in the column, you can use this instead:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Dim StartRng As Range, EndRng As Range
Set StartRng = ws.Range("C8")
Set EndRng = StartRng.End(xlDown)

Dim Targets() As Variant
Targets = ws.Range(StartRng, EndRng).Value
```

`StartRng.End(xlDown)` starts from your start range that you previously specified, then goes down. It will scan downwards until it finds the last cell that contains a value (before a blank) and use this as it's range. This means there could still be other cells with data below this range - because it only picked up the cell before the first empty cell.

---

You can test the array using this loop

```
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(Targets) To UBound(Targets)
    Debug.Print Targets(i, 1)
Next
```

to ensure your values are what you expect them to be.

Comment: So this will stop if it detects a blank? what is the .End(xlUp) mean in the situation?

Comment: `.End(xlUp)` will find the last row in the column. If you are actually wanting to the last cell before a blank (so there still may be data below it), you can replace the EndRng with this: `Set EndRng = StartRng.End(xlDown)`. I will update answer to include both varieties.